# Add track to currently playing playlist in iTunes using AppleScript

Tags: itunes, applescript, playlist

Using AppleScript, I can add a track to a playlist by using a command something like this:

```
duplicate myTrack to playlist "myPlaylist"
```

which works fine. However, if the playlist is currently playing, that track will never be played. How can I add a track to a playlist and get it to play when the playlist gets to it (not immediately)?

Comment: I'm surprised the song doesn't get played when added in this manner.  What about if you use *System Events* to access *iTunes* menu and adding the song to the Now Playing playing that way ?

Comment: @CJK Ewwww...... :-) Worth a shot though. I'll see if I can't figure that one out. Yeah, I was somewhat surprised it didn't play myself. I would think if you are playing a playlist, and you add a song to said playlist, it should play. Doesn't seem to work though, at least not in my testing so far.